# Unable to create site using saved site template SharePoint 2016

Tags: site-template

We have recently migrated our SharePoint from 2010 to 2016. After that none of the site templates which we used in 2010 are working. First it throws content type name error and then I renamed the content types and when I tried to create a new site using that template it throws an error "**Sorry, something went wrong 
An unexpected error has occurred.** "
When I save a site as template and try to create a site using that saved template it throws same error.
When I checked the log files with the correlation id it shows the below errors . I am literally blocked all ways with no ideas on how to proceed there are tons of sites which depends on site templates. Please suggest some solutions on this.

```
Failed to apply template "BLANKINTERNET#2" to web at URL "https://somesite.com/PMO/testmpo", error Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException 0x24fbc780
```

`The element of type 'ListInstance' for feature 'PMOTEMP2018ListInstances' (id: 76c38115-fadc-4a79-8870-203a86a801d0) threw an exception during activation:`

```
Feature Activation: Threw an exception, attempting to roll back.  Feature 'PMOTEMP2018ListInstances' (ID: '76c38115-fadc-4a79-8870-203a86a801d0').  Exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: <nativehr>0x8007047e</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateList(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, String bstrListUrl, String bstrFeatureId, Int32 lTemplateID, String bstrDocTemplateType, ListQuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, Boolean bProvisionViewsAndForms, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListInstanceModuleCallback, String bstrListInstanceSolutionInfo, String bstrListInstanceFeaturePath, String bstrListInstanceFeatureId, String bstrCustomSchemaXml, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListTemplateModuleCallback, String bstrListTemplateSolutionInfo)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateList(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, String bstrListUrl, String bstrFeatureId, Int32 lTemplateID, String bstrDocTemplateType, ListQuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, Boolean bProvisionViewsAndForms, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListInstanceModuleCallback, String bstrListInstanceSolutionInfo, String bstrListInstanceFeaturePath, String bstrListInstanceFeatureId, String bstrCustomSchemaXml, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListTemplateModuleCallback, String bstrListTemplateSolutionInfo)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.HandleProvisioningException(Exception e, Boolean force)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionListInstances(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)

```
Failed to activate site-scoped features for template 'BLANKINTERNET#2' in site 'https://somesite.com/PMO/testmpo'.


Failed to activate web features when provisioning site at url "https://somesite.com/PMO/testmpo" with site definition "BLANKINTERNET#2".

Failed to apply template "BLANKINTERNET#2" to web at URL "https://somesite.com/MO/testmpo".

Failed to apply template "BLANKINTERNET#2" to web at URL "https://somesite.com/MO/testmpo", error Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException 0x24fbc780


Exception in EnsureFeaturesActivatedAtWeb: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: <nativehr>0x8007047e</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateList(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, String bstrListUrl, String bstrFeatureId, Int32 lTemplateID, String bstrDocTemplateType, ListQuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, Boolean bProvisionViewsAndForms, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListInstanceModuleCallback, String bstrListInstanceSolutionInfo, String bstrListInstanceFeaturePath, String bstrListInstanceFeatureId, String bstrCustomSchemaXml, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListTemplateModuleCallback, String bstrListTemplateSolutionInfo)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateList(String bstrWebUrl, String bstrTitle, String bstrDescription, String bstrListUrl, String bstrFeatureId, Int32 lTemplateID, String bstrDocTemplateType, ListQuickLaunchOptions qlOpt, Boolean bProvisionViewsAndForms, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListInstanceModuleCallback, String bstrListInstanceSolutionInfo, String bstrListInstanceFeaturePath, String bstrListInstanceFeatureId, String bstrCustomSchemaXml, ISPEnableModuleCallback pListTemplateModuleCallback, String bstrListTemplateSolutionInfo)     -
 -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.HandleProvisioningException(Exception e, Boolean force)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionListInstances(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.EnsureFeaturesActivatedCore(SPSite site, SPWeb web, String sFeatures, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing)
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your templates from SharePoint 2010 will not work on SharePoint 2016. You must create a new template from the source (List/Library/Site) which you can then use for deployment of new assets.

Comment: Hi Trevor I tried creating new template using my existing site and when I try to create a site using that template it throws the above error. Are you saying me to create new site instead of the migrated site?

Comment: There can be various reasons (incompatibilities, missing features, etc.) that would prevent a template working from a migrated site. I would suggest creating a new site for templating purposes and see if that works. Otherwise, you'll need to dive into the specifics of why your upgraded site with a new template based on that upgraded site fails.

Comment: Sure I will try to create a new site similar to the one from 2010 and will try to save as template and start creating new site from it and will get back to you. thanks for the suggestion Trevor